# Filter post by users creation date

Tags: posts

I am working on a membership site and my client would like to hide member's only content from new subscribers. EX. If I create a new member today how can I keep the new member seeing previously created content?

TIA!

Comment: You will have to save the time when user registers and then you can update the conditions for displaying posts.

Comment: @Akshat is right. You need to fetch the user's registration date and use `pre_get_posts` to modify the query using `date_query`.